# Pressure in a hydraulic cylinder with piston in free fall?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I have a double-acting asymmetric hydraulic cylinder with chambers A and B (A has a larger area). The piston has a heavy weight mounted on it, and both chambers are connected to supply and return valves, respectively. As soon as the valve is opened, the pressure holding the piston in place is released, and thus the piston rushes down. The equation for chamber B in this case can simply be obtained by continuity.

$$
\dot{p}_B = \frac{\beta}{V_{B0} - A_B x}(A_B \dot{x} - Q_B)
$$

Where $\beta$ is the bulk's modulus of hydraulic oil, $V_{B0}$ is the initial volume in chamber B, $A_B$ is the area in chamber B, x and $\dot{x}$ are the piston position and velocity, respectively, and $Q_B$ is the flow coming out of chamber B.

[image: A simplified diagram of the hydraulic cylinder.]

Chamber A is a bit problematic, though, as it turns out, there are negative pressures in chamber A, and the flow out of B is much higher than that coming in from A. The continuity equation doesn't yield the correct results.

What would be the dynamic equation of pressure variation in chamber A?

Comment: Only the gauge pressure will be negative. Absolute pressure will remain positive however.